# Handling OAuth callback URL

Tags: oauth

I've been reading the OAuth 1.0a RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849 . Most of it is pretty clear. However, I have a few questions:

1. I can't understand why the `oauth_callback` is sent when obtaining an unauthorized request token. I mean, doesn't it make more sense for it to be sent when redirecting the user to the authorization page? That way, the server doesn't have to store the `oauth_callback` which is most likely going to be the same for all tokens for the same consumer.
2. Assume I don't want to store the `oauth_callback`. I request clients to send the `oauth_callback` when requesting an unauthorized token with the value `oob`. Then I request clients to send the `oauth_callback` in the query string of the authorization page (with the real callback URL). After reading this [section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-2.1) I understand this is RFC-compliant and still secure. However, I'd like to hear a second opinion